# How to retrieve image URL from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I searched a lot of questions on stack overflow, looking for an answer to this, but none of them are working for me.

I am using a code like following to upload an image from user's device to Firebase storage, and along with that, update the `imageURL` node in firebase with URL of the image uploaded.

```java
private void uploadFile(Bitmap bitmap) {

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

        final StorageReference ImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/"+mAu.getCurrentUser().getUid()+".jpg");


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        UploadTask uploadTask = ImagesRef.putBytes(data);



        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.i("whatTheFuck:",exception.toString());
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.



                Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mAu.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                Log.i("seeThisUrl", downloadUrl.toString());

                ref.child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());


            }
        });
```

But the imageURL is always not what I am expecting, it is something of the form:

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@51bc124

instead of actual URL, and I am not able to find an answer to why it's happening like that.

Comment: See this? https://github.com/udacity/and-nd-firebase/issues/41

Comment: @cricket_007: you need to wait for the task returned by `getDownloadUrl()` to complete, and then get the actual URL inside the `onSuccess` handler.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@51bc124
```

Because this is the address from memory of your `downloadUrl` object which is of type `Task<Uri>` and **not** the actual Uri.

According to the official documentation regarding on how to [get a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url):

> After uploading a file, you can get a URL to download the file by calling the `getDownloadUrl()` method on the StorageReference:

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("/* Your path */");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        return ref.getDownloadUrl(); //Call the getDownloadUrl() method
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
        } else {
            // Handle failures
        }
    }
});
```

This is an example from the docs.

Comment: I didn't understand which is the Url I need, `ref.getDownloadUrl()` or `downloadUri`

Comment: `downloadUri` is of type `Uri`. Try to print it, is it what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi Manhar! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?